# must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble creating a simple component that renders a menu in my react application.

This is the code for my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class menu extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }

}
```

I'm putting it in the other component.

```
import menu from './componentes/menu';
```

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { sistemas: [] };
  }

```
class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <menu></menu>
      </div>
      <div className="App">

        <div className="bs-header" id="content">
          <div className="container">
            <h1>Template Changelog</h1>
            <p>Lists all changes to the HTML template files</p>
          </div>
        </div>

); //[js] JSX expressions must have one parent element.
  }

}
```

I'm also getting the following error in the commented line

[js] JSX expressions must have one parent element.

Comment: fyi you should capitalize `menu`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `App` has more than one top level `div`. Wrap both in another `div`.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto its more of a JSX rule - basically you can't return multiple objects from the function.

Answer (score 5):

In React 16, you can wrap your components with `Fragment` which is a cleaner approach as compared to wrap it with additional `div` tag.

All you have to do is just import `Fragment` from react library.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
```

And you can use it

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentA />
  <ComponentB />
</Fragment>
```

Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Otherwise you can just wrap your components with `div` tag as mentioned by @Daniel A. White